# filtering on shiny selectizeInput and showing blank plot when there are no observations in the dataset that meet the input

Tags: r, shiny

In my flexdashboard shiny app, I'm using `selectizeInput()` with three options: "english", "spanish", and "other". In my toy dataset, there are no observations of the variable `lang` that take the value "other". Therefore, when **only** "other" is selected in the input bar, R returns an evaluation error:

> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

This is caused by the following line of the pipe in the "Page 1" section:

`filter(if(is.null(input$foo)) (new==1) else (lang %in% input$foo)) %>%`

What is the right approach to show a blank plot when there are no observations in the dataset that take the value of the input?

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: bootstrap
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  library(flexdashboard)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(tibbletime)
  library(dygraphs)
  library(magrittr)
  library(xts)
```

```{r global, include=FALSE}
# generate data
  set.seed(1)
  dat <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), 
                               as.Date("2018-06-30"), 
                               "days"),
                    sex = sample(c("male", "female"), 181, replace=TRUE),
                    lang = sample(c("english", "spanish"), 181, replace=TRUE),
                    age = sample(20:35, 181, replace=TRUE))
  dat <- sample_n(dat, 80)

```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
selectizeInput(
  'foo', label = NULL, 
  choices = c("english", "spanish", "other"),
  multiple = TRUE
)
```

Page 1
=====================================

```{r}
# all
  totals <- reactive({
  dat %>%
    mutate(new = 1) %>%
    arrange(date) %>%
    filter(if(is.null(input$foo)) (new==1) else (lang %in% input$foo)) %>%
  # time series analysis
  tibbletime::as_tbl_time(index = date) %>% # convert to tibble time object
    select(date, new) %>%
    tibbletime::collapse_by("1 week", side = "start", clean = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(total = sum(new, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    distinct(date, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # expand matrix to include weeks without data
    complete(
      date = seq(date[1], date[length(date)], by = "1 week"),
      fill = list(total = 0)
    )
  })

# convert to xts
  totals_ <- reactive({
    totals <- totals()
    xts(totals, order.by = totals$date)
  })

# plot
  renderDygraph({

  totals_ <- totals_()
  dygraph(totals_[, "total"]) %>%
    dyRangeSelector() %>%
    dyOptions(useDataTimezone = FALSE,
              stepPlot = TRUE,
              drawGrid = FALSE,
              fillGraph = TRUE) 
  })
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `shiny::req` function to check the requirements before running the code block.

If you add:

```
req(dat$lang %in% input$foo)
```

to the top of your  `totals <- reactive({` expression, then it will check that the value of `input$foo` is in `dat$lang` before running the rest of that expression. If it's not found, then the operation will be stopped silently. No error will be displayed and the plot will remain blank.

Comment: very cool. adding `req(dat$lang %in% input$foo)` gave me a blank plot by default when nothing was selected, so i added `req((dat$lang %in% input$foo) | is.null(input$foo))` to plot the unfiltered dataset. thanks!